# How can I know if my app is removed?

Tags: android

I'm a newbie. I don't know that when I publish my app, I wonder if it is removed. Is there any way to check if my app is disabled before I publish it?

Thanks and best regards
PS: my English is not good. Please be sympathetic!!!

Comment: Are you saying that you uploaded your app in the playstore and you wonder if it's removed or not? if that's the case, it will take a while for you to see your apps on the playstore (atleast 2 hours or so).

Comment: Your question does not make sense. https://translate.google.com/

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Google Play Store console, and check your app status